# convertir html a pdf

Tags: php, pdf

Tengo este codigo php quiero imprimir html a pdf pero no se que no funcione, me estoy basando en un video de YT pero no funciona.

```
<?php

    include ("connect_db.php");

    require_once('../libs/pdf/mpdf.php');

    $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
    $mpdf- >writeHTML('<div>hola.....</div>');
    $mpdf- >Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');


?>
```

Comment: Pon un header antes de sacar el PDF a ver si funciona: `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');`

Comment: O prueba así, si lo quieres mostrar en el navegador: `$mpdf- >Output();`

Comment: El header donde lo coloco? lo del output () no funcionó.

Comment: El header al principio del código. Enciende el modo de depuración, así sabrás qué error es. Algo así: `$mpdf = new Mpdf(['debug' => true]); $mpdf->WriteHTML("<p>Hello World</p>"); $mpdf->Output();` otra cosa que deberías probar es si estás incluyendo bien la librería. Eso se haría con un `var_dump($mpdf);` si arroja `NULL` o algo así es que no está creando la instancia.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas [html2pdf](https://github.com/iafan/html2pdf) solo tienes que hacer esto:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/php/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'Letter', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', array(5, 5, 15, 5));
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($contentHTML);
$salida=$html2pdf->Output("XML.pdf","S");
```